# How to get user's location with Yahoo API and post it to a div in my website

Tags: javascript, api, yahoo

I am a new javascript coder, so I'd like to know how can I get the user's geolocation with Yahoo API and post it to another existing div on my website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 Geolocation to get the latitudes and longitudes of the user and then pass this to Yahoo Placefinder API.

For e.g, the URL to query is:

```
var geoAPI='http://where.yahooapis.com/geocodelocation='+lat+','+lon+'&flags=J&gflags=R&appid='+APPID;
```

Notice we are passing the R flag for reverse geocoding.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am lost. I dont know anything about javascript, and that line of code didnt help me. Is is possible to create a simple jsfiddle with an example and full code?